# Accessing an iFrame outside React's scope?

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I'm currently wrapping a whole website made up of React components in an iFrame.

For example

```
<iframe id="checkout" src="https://react-website.onrender.com/" allowtransparency="true" ></iframe>
```

There is a React Close button component on my website (https://react-website.onrender.com/) that I want to essentially close the iFrame/set the iFrame to hidden. Is this even possible?